# Showing Validation messages with Reactive Forms and ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-reactive-forms, angular-changedetection

I'm trying to migrate an app to using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. However, I'm running into a bit of a blocker trying to work with some reactive forms.

I've got a reusable control that shows validation messages based on some of the state flags (e.g. `*ngIf="control.touched && control.invalid"`). The problem I'm running into is that there's no way to detect when the `touched` flag changes, and therefore no way to trigger change detection using `ChangeDetectorRef`.

It *could* be done with a reference to the input element itself by listening for a `click` event, but that doesn't account for when `markAsTouched()` is used, and passing a reference to the element around isn't always possible, and it's always inelegant.

Is there a way to use `OnPush` and still respond to the form control state (e.g. `touched`), or is it just generally painful?

Comment: lots of alternatives: https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: @pixelbits - that's just basically a walkthrough of how to use OnPush. Editing my question to clarify my main issue.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @miladfm not really. Ultimately, there isn't really a great way to use `OnPush` with Reactive form components unless Angular gets updated to add observables for those state changes. I ended up leaving the components with forms using the default strategy, and then using `OnPush` for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for status changes and then call `markForCheck()` to update the view:

```js
constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this.formGroup.statusChanges.subscribe(status => changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
}
```

UPDATE:
Since I can't comment, I will update this answer.

You are right about statusChanges. and of course you need to subscribe to statusChanges, it was a mistake.

I think we missed a point here. In `CheckOnce` mode (OnPush), Angular will check for changes after DOM events (including blur), so the view should be updated and the message you metioned (`*ngIf="control.touched && control.invalid"`) should work.

But if you call `markAsTouched()` in the code will not check for changes until you call `markForCheck()`.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-touched-sjhijt

Comment: `statusChanges` only deals with the validation state of the control (valid/invalid/dirty/pristine), and doesn't emit due to `touched` changing - https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl.

Also, FWIW, your syntax is incorrect ;) `statusChanges` is an observable, so you need to call `.subscribe` on it rather than just passing it a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are looking for the new way to create a ReactiveForm using the new FormGroup directly. Sorry if I did not understand your question. e.g.

```
//before
this.myForm=this.formBuilder({
   control1:''
   })
//after
this.myForm=new FormGroup({
   control1:new FormControl(''),
},{ updateOn: 'blur' })
```

Comment: Not exactly - the problem I'm particularly running into is triggering an update based on the "touched" property changing. For example, when a parent component calls "markAsTouched" on a control.